# Further filter QuerySet when moving from one URL to another

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls, django-filter

I'm learning Python Django. I'm trying to create an Expense Tracker App. I record an expense  transaction and attach it against a Category and a Subcategory. E.g. Category would be Travel, Sub category would be Hotel.

I then record a transaction on a specific date providing Category/Subcategory. My Model is as below.

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_text

class SubCategories(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name="category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory_text

class Transaction(models.Model):
    card_source = models.ForeignKey(CardSource, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategories, related_name="subcategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    transaction_date = models.DateField('Date')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description + ' on ' + str(self.transaction_date) + ' via ' + str(self.card_source)
```

My index.html view shows all sum of all expenses per category for last 30 days.

```
# /expenses/<x>days/
def last_xdays(request, num_of_days):
    last_xdays_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=num_of_days)
    transaction_list = Transaction.objects.filter(transaction_date__gte=last_xdays_date).filter(
        transaction_date__lte=date.today())
    if not transaction_list:
        raise Http404("No transactions found.")
    category_list = Categories.objects.annotate(category_sum=Sum('category__subcategory__amount', filter=Q(
        category__subcategory__id__in=transaction_list))).filter(category_sum__gt=0)
    return render(request, 'expenses/index.html',
                  {'category_list': category_list, 'transaction_list': transaction_list})
```

**Requirement:**
When I click on a Category, it should navigate to url [/expenses/30days/Travel][1] showing sum of all expenses per subcategory under that category.

Template:

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{% url 'expenses:category' category.id %}">{{ category.category_text }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ category.category_sum }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
```

E.g. When I click on category 'Travel', it should now show me expenses summed up at subcategory level like 'Hotel', 'Flights' but only for the last 30 days. The problem I have is how would view know that the original View is already filtered for 30 days? So when I filter expenses at a subcategory level, I only consider expenses made in last 30 days.

I have more filter on top of the page like filter expenses for last 90 days. In that case the view will sum up all expenses per category made in last 90 days. Again, when I click on Category, I need to fetch all expenses for that category for last 90 days and show them summed up at subcategory level.

Problem is, when I click on category, how would view know the existing filter on date i.e. if the view is filtered for last 30 days or 60 days or 90 days, etc? Also, how to navigate to a url like [https:///expenses/60days/Travel]?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a URL like this:

```
/expenses/60days/
```

You can put this in your HTML links:

```
<a href="{{ sub_category }}">
```

Becomes

```
<a href="travel">
```

Which is the same as

```
<a href="/expenses/60days/travel/"
```

Without the prefixed forward slash, the link becomes relative and clicking it just adds 'travel' to the current URL.